# Why $N$ is not the function of $\varepsilon$?

Tags: calculus

Here is a calculus question:

$N$ is not the function of $\varepsilon$ in $\varepsilon-N$ definition.

I cannot understand why? In my opinion, every time we try to find a suitable $N$ which based on $\varepsilon$, that is, $N=N(\varepsilon)$. Why it is not a function? 

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. How are you using $N,\epsilon?$ Is there some sequence?

Comment: For a given $\epsilon$, you can find many $N$ satisfy $\epsilon-N$ language, so ...

Or, you only need find a sufficient large $N$ depends on $\epsilon$, not necessary be a precise integer.

Comment: This is a homework question in $\varepsilon-N$ definition part. True/False.

Comment: The choice of an appropriate $N$ certainly depends on the earlier choice of $\epsilon$. However, calling this dependency a *function* would carry the extra load of implying that only a single choice of $N$ works. That is never the case.

Comment: Yes, it is in calculus-1 course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you an example:

Prove: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$$

Proof: This is easy to see that we have to find a $N$, for every $n>N$ it satisfies 
$$|\frac{1}{n}-0|<\varepsilon\Rightarrow n>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$$
Thus we can choose $N=[\frac{1}{\varepsilon}]+1$, while this is not the ONLY choice, which means you can also choose $N=[\frac{1}{\varepsilon}]+2,\ N=[\frac{1}{\varepsilon}]+3$, etc. Each of them will satisfy $\varepsilon-N$ definition.

As you mentioned that "$N$ is based on $\varepsilon$", correct! But $N$ is not the ONLY one value which means it is not a function of $\varepsilon$ but we can say it is an expression of $\varepsilon$.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

May I say that I don't completely agree? Not to mention that there are also multivalued functions, there is nothing really wrong in thinking of $N$ as a function of $\varepsilon$. For instance, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is always a *smallest* $N$ as in the definition of limits, since any part of $\mathbb{N}$ has a minimum. 
Of course this is not the only way to define $N(\varepsilon)$, but I believe that such subtleties are really dangerous in a calculus course.

Comment: This is from a Chinese calculus-1 textbook and the answer is TRUE. I think maybe it is just an elemental level in calculus. I think every $\varepsilon$ can define a "best" $N$ which means it is the function of $\varepsilon$. Am I right?